# I want a query that uses my 'favorite' and 'rejected' tags in a very basic way

Tags: support, tag-filters

I want a filter that does the following:
- 1 site only (!)
- finds questions that match any of my favorite tags
- but none of the tags I've identified as never interesting to me

The closest I've found is:

- The canned "favorite tags" filter, which matches on all sites, and includes questions with tags I've identified as never interesting (e.g. computer languages I don't know)
- The build-your-own-filter page, which requires me to reenter the list of favorite tags, and still has no ability to reject certain tags.
- Someone asking feedback for a complex query to find questions like those someone has just answered at 
  [Help build a good "Find The Next Question To Answer" query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289702/help-build-a-good-find-the-next-question-to-answer-query?cb=1)

Have you got such capabilities buried somewhere?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something because I don't filter that much, but doesn't every filter correspond to a unique URL that you can bookmark?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by combination of the  following:

1. On your [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current), click 
   Edit Profile & Settings -> Preferences -> **Hide questions in your ignored tags**
2. Use the search query `intags:mine is:q`, sorting results by newest. [Like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aq).